# Set and modify a value in a select box with knockout

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

Well, I have two problems that worry me a lot ... First, I don't know how to give a default value to the select box.

And I I'm not able to change the value of the select box via an event click ... I've created a fiddle example if someone could give me a hand it would be very appreciated!

**HTML**

```
<select id="FilterBox" data-bind="value: siteGetOne">
  <option value="-2">City Wide</option>
  <!-- ko foreach: sites -->
  <option data-bind="text: name, value: $data"></option>
  <!-- /ko -->
</select>

Selection Option Object : <span data-bind="text: siteGetOne"></span><br/>
Selection Option name : <span data-bind="text: siteGetOne().name"></span><br/>
Selection Option id : <span data-bind="text: siteGetOne().id"></span><br/>

<a href="#" data-bind="click: setValue(1);">Set Value to 1</a>
<a href="#" data-bind="click: setValue(2);">Set Value to 2</a>
<a href="#" data-bind="click: setValue(3);">Set Value to 3</a>
```

**JS**

```
var viewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    setValue = ko.observable();

    self.sites = [
      { name: 'Site 1', id: 1},
      { name: 'Site 2', id: 2},
      { name: 'Site 3', id: 3}
    ];

    self.siteGetOne = ko.observable(self.sites[2].id);

    self.siteGetOne.subscribe(function (newValue) {
      console.log(newValue);
    }, self);
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xjYcu/276/

**Edited Final version** : http://jsfiddle.net/xjYcu/286/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

couple things you may want to change.
here is the entire fiddle.    http://jsfiddle.net/xjYcu/283/

the first one is you should use the options binding for your select.

```
<select id="FilterBox" data-bind=" options: sites,
            optionsText: 'name',
            value: siteGetOne,
            optionsCaption: 'Choose...'">

</select>
```

also try changing your click bindings to something like this so you can pass in your parameter.

```
<a href="#" data-bind="click: function () {setValue(0)}">Set Value to 1</a>
<a href="#" data-bind="click: function () {setValue(1)}">Set Value to 2</a>
<a href="#" data-bind="click: function () {setValue(2)}">Set Value to 3</a>
```

Comment: Thanks Bryan, I have edited my main post with OptionCaption as an array item